# Combine multiple exclusion (<>) criteria in AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have worked around my issue by using this dirty hack:

```
    ' Filter managerial functions
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BW$2211").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>Head*", _
    Criteria2:="<>IT*", Operator:=XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BW$2211").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>Local Head*", _
    Criteria2:="<>Resp*", Operator:=XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BW$2211").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>Team Lead*", _
    Criteria2:="<>XB*", Operator:=XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd
```

Is there any way to combine these 3 statements into one line? Excel seems to have a problem as soon as I have a third criteria (Criteria3) in one line. Furthermore, <>Array() seems not to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

An advanced filter might be more suitable for this purpose.

You could also do something like this:

```
Dim bUnion As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim vData As Variant
Dim rDataHide As Range

vData = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("$AJ$1:$AJ$2211"))
bUnion = False

For i = 1 To 2211
  If LenB(vData(i)) Then
    If vData(i) Like Whatever Or vData(i) Like Whatever2 Then
      If bUnion Then
        Set rDataHide = Union(rDataHide, ActiveSheet.Range("$AJ$" & i))
      Else
        Set rDataHide = ActiveSheet.Range("$AJ$" & i)
        bUnion = True
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next i
rDataHide.Rows.Hidden = True
```

You could even use RegEx, I haven't really used RegEx much before though so you would have to google it.

Comment: AFAIK, I need a range in my worksheet to use advanced filter. I prefer to have pure VBA code with all the criteria in one array (which does not work for <>).

Comment: You could create the advanced filter range with VBA though if needed. or even just add a working column with an OR test, AutoFilter that, then destroy the working column when finished

Comment: I do the what brettdj does when I use advanced filter, create the filter range then delete it after I'm done using it. You could also try what I put above in the edited answer.