# VBA - "does not contain"-filter (excel 2010)

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine multiple exclusion (<>) criteria in AutoFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662659/combine-multiple-exclusion-criteria-in-autofilter)

I'm trying to set up a filter with multiple 'Does not containt' values. I seem to get an error doh every time I try to run it. I've looked up this error and it means that excel didn't find any value's. When I try to run the same code, only with one value, it works fine. Any help/suggestions?

Code with multiple values:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$218").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("<>*a*", "<>*b*", "<>*c*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Code with only one value:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$218").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*a*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Greetz
Bulki

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$218").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*a*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*b*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<>*c*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Failing that, have you tried recording what you want as a Macro as copying/adapting the recorded code to do what you want?

Comment: Didn't work, tried recording it, but it failed even the possibility to do this. I've ended up writing my own C# filter program but still am curious about this problem doh.